# Lazily grouping a flat sequence in F#

Tags: recursion, f#, immutability

Given a sequence of items as follows:

```
[ ("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 3); ("b", 1); ("c", 2); ("c", 3) ]
```

How can I convert this lazily into:

```
{ ("a", { 1; 2; 3}); ("b", { 1 }); ("c", { 2; 3}) }
```

You can assume that the input data source is already sorted on the grouping key element e.g. "a" "b" and "c".

I'm using the { } there to indicate that it's a lazily-evaluated sequence of items.

I've gotten it working imperatively with two while loops operating over the IEnumerator of the source sequence, but this involves creating reference variables and mutation etc. etc. I'm sure that there are better ways of doing this, perhaps with Recursion or using some of the operations in the Seq library e.g. scan or unfold?

Comment: I did something similar a while back, also with some mutation: http://rojepp.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/sql-optimization-trick-in-f/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to implement this over `IEnumerable<'T>` (to make it lazy), then it is necessarily going to be somewhat imperative, because the `IEnumerator<'T>` type that is used to iterate over the input is imperative. But the rest can be written as a recursive function using sequence expressions.

The following is lazy in the first level (it produces each group lazily), but it does not produce elements of the group lazily (I think that would have pretty subtle semantics):

```
/// Group adjacent elements of 'input' according to the 
/// keys produced by the key selector function 'f'
let groupAdjacent f (input:seq<_>) = seq {
  use en = input.GetEnumerator()

  // Iterate over elements and keep the key of the current group
  // together with all the elements belonging to the group so far
  let rec loop key acc = seq { 
    if en.MoveNext() then 
      let nkey = f en.Current 
      if nkey = key then 
        // If the key matches, append to the group so far
        yield! loop key (en.Current::acc)
      else 
        // Otherwise, produce the group collected so far & start a new one
        yield List.rev acc
        yield! loop nkey [en.Current]
    else
      // At the end of the sequence, produce the last group
      yield List.rev acc
  }
  // Start with the first key & first value as the accumulator
  if en.MoveNext() then 
    yield! loop (f en.Current) [en.Current] }
```

Unfortunately, this (pretty useful!) function is not included in the standard F# library, so if you want to group *adjacent* elements (rather than arbitrary elements in the list using `Seq.groupBy`), you have to define it yourself...

Answer (score 4):

```
let p = [("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 3); ("b", 1); ("c", 2); ("c", 3)]
let l = p |> Seq.groupBy fst |> Seq.map(fun x -> fst x, snd x |> Seq.map snd)
```

Comment: Using `Seq.groupBy` ignores the fact that _"You can assume that the input data source is already sorted on the grouping key element"_ and as a result it cannot produce the groups lazily which is what the OP was asking about... So this produces the right result, but not lazily (which was the point of the question).

Comment: thank you Tomas for explaining why this wasn't what I was after (but thanks OP for the suggestion)

Answer (score 3):

In [F#+](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharpPlus/) there is a generic function [chunkBy](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/ad2bf4d74750a4e4bac81642338e7553c41ced14/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L327) that can be used to do that:

```
#r "FSharpPlus.dll"
open FSharpPlus

seq [ ("a", 1); ("a", 2); ("a", 3); ("b", 1); ("c", 2); ("c", 3) ]
    |> chunkBy fst 
    |> map (fun (x,y) -> x, map snd y)
```

And it works with `seq`, `array` and `list`.

The implementation for `seq` is pretty much the same as the `groupdAdjacent` from Tomas.

Comment: FsControl looks like a very nice idea.. I did not know about this

Answer (score 1):

```
Seq.groupBy fst
```

Will do the trick

Comment: This would give you `("a", [ ("a",1), ("a", 2) .. ] )`.

Comment: More importantly, I think that Isaac is asking how to group _adjacent_ elements, rather than any elements in the input with the same key...

Comment: Not quite, it will give you an seq<string * seq<string * int>>

Comment: Also won't groupby have to go over the entire collection to get the groupings - i don't want to do that because i know a grouping ends once the key changes