# Equivalent of repeated takeWhile calls: does this function have a "standard" name?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have a scenario where the standard `List.groupBy` function isn't what I want, but I don't know the right name for this function so it's making it hard to search for.

I have a list of items of type `'T`, and a `'T -> 'k` key-producing function. The items are already somewhat "grouped" together in the list, so that when you map the list through the key function, its result will tend have the same key in a row several times, e.g. `[1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 1; 1; 3; 3; 3; 1; 1]`. What I want is to get a list of lists, where the inner list contains all the items for which the key-producing function returned the same value -- but it should NOT group the different sequences of 1's together.

In other words, say my data was a list of strings, and the key-producing function was `String.length`. So the input is:

```
["a"; "e"; "i"; "to"; "of"; "o"; "u"; "and"; "for"; "the"; "I"; "O"]
```

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
[["a"; "e"; "i"]; ["to"; "of"]; ["o"; "u"]; ["and"; "for"; "the"]; ["I"; "O"]]
```

To think of it another way: this is like taking the first item of the list and storing the result of calling the key function. Then you'd use `takeWhile (fun x -> keyFun x = origKeyFunResult)` to generate the first segment. Then when that `takeWhile` stops returning values, you record when it stopped, and the value of `keyFun x` on the first value that didn't return the original result -- and go on from there. (Except that that would be O(N*M) where M is the number of sequences, and would devolve into O(N^2) in many cases -- whereas it should be possible to implement this function in O(N) time).

Now, I can write that function pretty easily. That's not the question. What I want to know is whether there's a standard **name** for this function. Because I thought it would be called `groupBy`, but that's something else. (`List.groupBy String.length` would return `[(1, ["a"; "e"; "i"; "o"; "u"; "I"; "O"]); (2, ["to"; "of"]), (3, ["and"; "for"; "the"])]`, but what I want in this case is for the "a/e/i", "o/u", and "I/O" lists to remain separated, and I don't want the value that the key-generating returns to be in the output data).

Maybe there isn't a standard name for this function. But if there is, what is it?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard name.  You should go ahead and write this; you already said it's easy to write, and the code you write for the function will serve to document what it does.

Comment: It's called `GatherBy` in Mathematica, which has somewhat functional roots.

Comment: In my experience this function was given name `split`. It refers to split function on strings which do similar thing.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846907/grouping-adjacent-elements-in-a-list

Comment: Also see [groupAdjBy](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus/blob/f01ca982a80c8e3fbb189c9da9508257d20a8c8f/FSharpPlus/Operators.fs#L302), which is like your function but generic, I mean it works with Arrays, Lists and Seqs.

Comment: [GroupAdjacent](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs) in [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) as well.

Comment: Clojure has this and I like the name for it: [`partition-by`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by)

Comment: This one is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753124/lazily-grouping-a-flat-sequence-in-f and [here's](http://www.fssnip.net/6A) a snippet.

Comment: How about naming it `chunk` or `chunkBy`, because of the similarities with `List.chunkBySize`. Both create a list of lists preserving the order of the original list, other one chunking by size and other chunking by predicate.

Comment: Yes, my vote goes for ``chunkBy`` . Then ``chunk`` for the version that doesn't take a mapper. It seems it's already defined in D https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/iteration/chunk_by.html

Comment: One more vote for something along the lines of `groupAdjacent`: http://www.fssnip.net/mI

Comment: And one more vote for something along the lines of `chunkBy`: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-seriesmodule.html#section1

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback! I had originally named the function `clusterBy` when I implemented it, but I agree that `chunkBy` is the best name in F# (other names might be better for other languages), given that `chunkBySize` already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late and it seems that you have found a solution, and it seems that there doesn't exists a single function i F# that can handle the problem.

Just for the challenge I tried to find some usable solutions and came up with the following (whether they are efficient or not is up the reader to deside):

```
open System

module List = 
  /// <summary>
  /// Generic List Extension:
  /// Given a comparer function the list will be chunked into sub lists
  /// starting when ever comparer finds a difference.
  /// </summary>
  let chunkByPredicate (comparer : 'T -> 'T -> bool) list = 
    let rec func (i : int, lst : 'T list) : 'T list list =
      if i >= lst.Length then
        List.empty
      else
        let first = lst.[i]
        let chunk = lst |> List.skip(i) |> List.takeWhile (fun s -> comparer first s)
        List.append [chunk] (func((i + chunk.Length), lst))

    func (0, list) |> List.where (fun lst -> not (List.isEmpty lst))

// 1. Using List.fold to chunk by string length
let usingListFold (data : string list) = 
  printfn "1. Using List.fold: "
  data 
  |> List.fold (fun (acc : string list list) s -> 
                  if acc.Length > 0 then
                    let last = acc.[acc.Length - 1]
                    let lastLength = last.[0].Length
                    if lastLength = s.Length then
                      List.append (acc |> List.take (acc.Length - 1)) [(last |> List.append [s])]
                    else
                      List.append acc  [[s]]
                  else
                    [[s]]) ([])

  |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
  printfn ""

// 2. Using List.chunkByPredicate
let usingListChunkByPredicate<'a> (predicate : 'a -> 'a -> bool, data : 'a list) = 
  printfn "2. Using List.chunkByPredicate: "
  data
  |> List.chunkByPredicate predicate
  |> List.iter (printfn "%A")
  printfn ""

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let data = ["a"; "e"; "i"; "to"; "of"; "o"; "u"; "and"; "for"; "the"; "I"; "O"]

  usingListFold data
  usingListChunkByPredicate<string>((fun first s -> first.Length = s.Length), data)

  let intData = [0..50]
  usingListChunkByPredicate<int>((fun first n -> first / 10 = n / 10), intData)

  Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  0
```